# GraphQL return Any how to decode in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, graphql

I am using script to build all apollo client queries automatically from the schema.
GraphQL have type Any in backend and can return String, Bool, Int, Float.
How to decode this?

I am getting error, because now AnyValue is set to String

`couldNotConvert(value: AnyHashable(false), to: Swift.String)`

Comment: Just decode it in String and add few computed property for Bool, Int, Float

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution is creating custom type "CustomScalarType"